# slideshow jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a big banner on a site. And, now I want that pictures in banner is changeing every 5 seconds, for example ( something like slider). Problem in that on the image draw a "widget". This "widget" contain description, the some links( and this information is specific for every image).  See exmaple on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XSywC/), please.

And, I have question, which a jquery plugin can do it for me?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using the [Carousel jquery plugin that comes with Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#carousel).

See this link:

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#carousel

Twitter Bootstrap is one of the most widely supported javascript / css libraries available with over [28,000 watchers in github](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap).

Answer (score 0):

Provided the "widget" is in a different div and CSS positions it over top of the slideshow, most any slideshow jQuery plugin will do.

Comment: I've used many, and don't really have a preference.  I hate to sound callus, but what have you found in Google?

Comment: In the google I found a lot of plugin, but I don't know what is better. I have not used them before.

Answer (score 0):

For a big banner like that you can check the list of plugins suites to your need here [Jquery Slider Plugins](http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/100-jquery-sliders-part1/) you can check the list of plugins there.